# sorting a string NSTableView Column having float values in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, nstableview

I have a NSTableView with columns having string type attribute. The values being displayed in the string column are float numbers. I am not able able to sort that column by clicking on the column header.

Comment: You will probably have to override the datasource method - (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView sortDescriptorsDidChange:(NSArray *)oldDescriptors
and then sort the data accordingly. Or else if you are using binding, you may have to set the key path for sorting in the xib itself.

Comment: I am using binding with an array controller bound to a list. I used "keyForCloumn.intValue" in the sorting options.The result is like - the fields which are not nil are sorted properly but the nil rows come in between the non-nil rows. For e.g. if i have 10 rows having values- 4.5,nil,nil,nil,1.2,0.6,0.5,-0.8,-2.4,-1.6 then it is being sorted as- 4.5,1.2,0.6,nil,nil,0.5,nil,-0.8,-1.6,-2.4 Where nil rows resides in between -1 and 1, occurring at random places.